# jQuery each() return unexpected results on iOS

Tags: jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I'm having issues with jQuery each() and find() methods in iOS Safari and on iOS devices.

squareTextWidth does not return anything in iOS, while on PC it returns the correct offsetWidth value. In fact `squareText[0]` does not exist in Safari context.

`console.log(squareText)` returns the DOM object in the JS console in Safari.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a workaround?

```js
function example() {
  $('div.access').each(function() {
    let squareText = $(this).find('.text');
    let squareTextWidth = squareText[0].offsetWidth;
    console.log(squareTextWidth);
  });
}
example();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 3</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 4 Longer text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan There you go, should have thought about that

Comment: Have you tried squareTextWidth = squareText.get(0).offsetWidth ? See https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index

Comment: @MartinLisowski yes indeed I have tried with get(0) method, same result

Comment: So does squareText.get(0) return return a DOM object or null? What is the value of squareText.length ? (it should be the number of element selected by the find() call, i.e. it should be 1 in your example).

Answer (score 1):

You code seems to work in Safari iOS 16 Let's see if this one works better in your Safari too:

You are in principle not getting what you think you are, and it seems some browsers do not mind and some do:

```
let $x = $(selector).find(otherSelector); // returns a jQuery collection
let y = $x[0]; // tricky. You want the DOM element but get the first jQuery element in the collection
let z = $x.eq(0)[0]; // better. Get the DOM element from the first jQuery element in the collection
```

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
function example() {
  $('div.access').each(function() {
    let $squareText = $(this).find('.text');
    let squareTextWidth = $squareText.eq(0)[0].offsetWidth;
    output.innerHTML += `${$squareText.eq(0).text()}: ${squareTextWidth}<hr />`;
  });
}
example();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 3</span>
</div>
<div class="access">
  <span class="text">Example text 4 Longer text</span>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Result:

Chrome 111.0.5563.146 (Official Build) (x86_64) OSX

```
Example text 1: 97
Example text 2: 97
Example text 3: 97
Example text 4 Longer text: 176
```

Safari OSX 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.6)

```
Example text 1: 97
Example text 2: 97
Example text 3: 97
Example text 4 Longer text: 176
```

Safari iOS 16.4

```
Example text 1: 97
Example text 2: 97
Example text 3: 97
Example text 4 Longer text: 176
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately $squareText.eq(0)[0].offsetWidth still returns 0 on Safari on macOS and iOS, returns the correct values on any other browsers.

Comment: What versions? I cannot reproduce this on any browser on Windows, OSX or iOS

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is indeed working in the snippet, and in a simple html file at the root of my hosting space, not working in my project environment with wordpress though. What startles me is that it works on all browsers, just not on safari, i'll investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so my `.text` is in fact an absolutely positionned `<span>` with inline-flex and several other flex properties, and safari was unable to calculate offsetWidth, but other browsers could.
Changed it to a `<p>` tag and now it works fine.

My mind was focused on the wrong part of the issue.

Thanks for your help.